# What is wakelock and how is it related to permissions?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I am listening to video regarding android doze and app standby, in that video speaker used wakelocks terminology.

Any source or blog-spot to understand it better is appreciated.

Comment: Please note: *Questions asking us to recommend or **find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: Should be duplicate of tag info - http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-wake-lock/info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, wakelock term is used whenever you want to wake your device up from sleep mode, like if your device is on sleep mode and you get a new notification, so you will be wanting wakelock permission to wake the device from sleep mode and show the status of notification.

Comment: Thank you for simple definition and it make lot of sense to me now.

Comment: You can upvote  the answer , if it is useful to you or you accept the answer if it is something that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wakelock for keeping the screen turned on - you can see an [example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) in this code.

If you want more information, you have to specify your question.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link and class PowerManager.WakeLock gives clear idea :

A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to have the device stay on.